# [ros2cli] Cannot get the lifecycle state of lifecycle demo nodes?

Tags: ros2, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to get the lifecycle of the lifecycle demo node `lifecycle_listener` but got `Node not found`.

In terminal A:

```
$ ros2 daemon start
The daemon has been started
$ ros2 run lifecycle lifecycle_listener
```

In terminal B:

```
$ ros2 lifecycle get lifecycle_listener
Node not found
```

Even if I try to get the lifecycle from the node launched with the launch file with `$ ros2 launch lifecycle lifecycle_demo.launch.py` I get `Node not found`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297183/%5Bros2cli%5D-cannot-get-the-lifecycle-state-of-lifecycle-demo-nodes?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-07-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please run `ros2 node list` in the terminal B to see the names of running nodes. You will see that the node name is actually `lc_listener`. You could also use tab completion in a shell like bash to provide the available name: `ros2 lifecycle get <tab>`.

Anyway the result is still  `Node not found`. If you call `ros2 service list` you will see that the listener node only has parameter related services (not sure why that is the case). Please try to run the `lifecycle_talker` instead. That one shows the lifecycle related service and will also report the lifecycle state correctly.

PS: You don't have to start the daemon manually. That happens automatically when needed.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-07-12**:
Ah, makes total sense then...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this is to be expected.

It might be misleading, but the `lifecycle_listener` is actually a regular node, and not a lifecylcle node.
https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/lifecycle/src/lifecycle_listener.cpp#L34

The listener node here is only showcasing the events getting published when a lifecycle node is changing state.
The functionality you're looking for should work for the `lifecycle talker` (https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/lifecycle/src/lifecycle_talker.cpp#L53).

Terminal A:

```
 ➭ ros2 run lifecycle lifecycle_talker
```

Terminal B:

```
 ➭ ros2 lifecycle get lc_talker
unconfigured [1]
```

---

Originally posted by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) with karma: 643 on 2018-07-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1